# How to draw a polyline with webgl earth

Tags: webgl-earth

I am trying to draw a polyline between multiple coordinates using webgl earth. There is an [API](http://www.webglearth.org/) for drawing a polygon but I can't seem to find anything equivalent for a polyline.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Use polygon, set 3 waypoint,  A/B/A, then you get a super simple polyline !